# Client side validation Without Using Javascript Or VB Script

Tags: java, validation, client-side

I have a servlet application that page is an html form. I'd like to add some client-side code to validate the data. I'd like to avoid using java script or any Microsoft or flash based technologies. Is it possible with java technology.

Answer (score 1):

You will have a VERY limited option when you do not want to use Javascript (not sure why). You have validation as a field attribute (like `maxlength` on input field ) which are **very limited**. Client side validation is always done along with Server side validation. They compliment each other.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Java applet, and render your user input controls using that instead of with an HTML form.

…but that way lies madness, it would be time consuming to build, take significantly longer to load than HTML + JS, and requires a browser plugin.

You really should use JavaScript for this, it is the only widely supported technology that can interact with HTML forms (without using JS as an intermediary).

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Java Applets

   - Here you can use a lot of layouts to position your elements.
2. If you are saying to use no JS in the terms of coding you can use
   GWT coding which is a normal java classes coding but it's a JS
   under.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameter of the HTML form to the Servlet and validate the form data
for eg:

```
String uName= request.getParameter("userName");
String pwd= request.getParameter("password");
PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();

if(uName.equals("username") && pwd.equals("password")){

out.println("Valid User");

}

else
out.println("Invalid User");
```

Comment: Hi Nishant thanks for your great answer, but I need dynamic client side validation also. Here you check the form after going to server. right?

Comment: Java Applet is a kind of application that running on the client's browser, when a browser request a applet embedded page, the applet will downloaded to the client computer and executed within the browser.

Servlets is a application that running on the server, when a server receive a request of a servlet, the server will process the servlet and give the result to the client back after the servlet is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formcheck :- mootools validations.. easy and simple to use..

```
http://mootools.floor.ch/en/demos/formcheck/
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple validation you can use standart HTML attributes for inputs, such as
`<input type='text' maxlength=10>` - not allows to type more then X symbols;
`<input type="email">` -not allows to type not e-mail pattern in WebKit-based browsers.
etc.
Look w3c docs for more information.
But you should always remeber, that client side validation should only minimize capacity on server and **data always should be validated on server side too**.